# Not able to map the response received in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm writing a react redux based web application, and I am not able to map out the response which I get from the redux store. I always get an error saying map is not a function. I am able to view the data via the console by logging it but it crashes the next second i use a map function to retrieve them. This is the response and I'm not able to map any of the data.

[image: JSON RESPONSE]

This is the code I created to get the blockcount response.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPost } from '../../Redux/Post-Redux/PostActionMethods';
import './PostBody.css';


function PostBody({postdata}) {

    console.log(postdata);

    var blockcount = postdata.postchapter.map((key)=>{
        return key.blockcount
    })
    
    console.log(blockcount);
    
    return postdata.isLoading ? (<h2>Loading...</h2>) :
            postdata.error ? (<h2>{postdata.error}</h2>) :
            (
                <div>
                    <p>Some texts</p>
                </div>
            )
    
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        postdata:state.PostChapter
    }
}


export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(PostBody);
```

When i run this i get the error: **TypeError: postdata.postchapter.map is not a function**

How do i rectify this and obtain the content response while im not able to retrieve the blockcount itself??

This is the content response i need to retrieve correctly.

[image]

Comment: Is postdata.postchapter an array? Are u trying to map postdata.postchapter.content ?

Comment: `postdata.postchapter` appears to be an object in the console log. There is nothing to map unless you are really wanting to map `postdata.postchapter.content`. What are you wanting to render, `postdata.postchapter.blockcount`?

Comment: I would like to find a way  to render the content response which holds 59 objects, how do i do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is method of an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), but `postdata.postchapter` is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Can't you just use

```
var blockcount = postdata.postchapter.blockCount;
```

instead of

```
var blockcount = postdata.postchapter.map((key)=>{
    return key.blockcount
})
```

-- Edit --

If you need to render `postdata.postchapter.content`;

`text` property for example,

then:

```
function PostBody({postdata}) {

    console.log(postdata);

    var content = postdata.postchapter.content?.map((item, index)=>{
        return <p key={index}>{item.text}</p>
    })
    
    return postdata.isLoading ? (<h2>Loading...</h2>) :
            postdata.error ? (<h2>{postdata.error}</h2>) :
            (
                <div>
                    {content}
                </div>
            )
    
}
```

[Here is react documentation about rendering lists](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: I'm able to do that. Thank you, but how do I render out all the data in the content object which holds 59 objects ??

Comment: How does `content` array look like? Show us output of `console.log(postdata.postchapter.content[0])`

Comment: Ive added the image please check it out

Comment: The answer works really well, but however when i refresh the page, I get an error saying that Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.  How do  I over come this ??

Comment: I edited answer. Notice `?` after `content`. Does it work now?

Comment: I tried giving content s static default variable and it worked for me. Thank you so much. I'll try out your responsr too !